# Hook into Add menu link in Drupal 8

Tags: menu, hook, drupal-8

I need to hook into "Add menu link" form in Drupal 8 and make Description field required.
This is for main navigation. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```js
// make description required for "Add menu link" form
  if ($form_id == 'menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form') {
     $form['description']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = true;

  }
```